# c# Can send data though serial port but not receive

Tags: c#, serial-port

so I have a PTZ camera connected to the PC though a serial port and I can send commands to it to control it. My problem is when I ask it which zoom it has, or anything, I will never get a response.

First, I open my Serial port:

```
public static void StartCOM(string COMPort, ref SerialPort serialPort)
{
    serialPort = new SerialPort(COMPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
    serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
    serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
}
```

Then I add the event to trigger when I receive data:

```
serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);
private void OnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Log("Data recibida");
    Debug.Log(serialPort.ReadExisting());
}
```

And then I open it:

```
public static void OpenCOM(ref SerialPort serialPort)
{
    //Comprobamos si el serial port existe
    if (serialPort != null)
    {
        //Si ya está abierto no hacemos nada
        if (serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            Debug.Log("El puerto " + serialPort.PortName + " ya estaba abierto");
        }
        //Si está cerrado lo abrimos
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Abrimos puerto: " + serialPort.PortName);
            serialPort.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I write to it a command that is supossed to return me something, but it never does:

```
 byte[] byteToSend = { 0x81, 0x09, 0x04, 0x00, 0xFF };
 COMUtility.WriteToCOM(serialPort, byteToSend);
```

The page where I get the commands from its: https://www.epiphan.com/userguides/LUMiO12x/Content/UserGuides/PTZ/3-operation/VISCAcommands.htm#CamValues

UPDATE:

So, I started to read data.

i write to the COM port:

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        //DebugAbsolutePosition();
        byte[] checkZoom = {0x81, 0x09, 0x04, 0x47, 0xFF };
        COMUtility.WriteToCOM(serialPort, checkZoom);
    }

    try
    {
        string data = serialPort.ReadExisting();
        Debug.Log("Data leida");
        Debug.Log(data);
    }
    catch { }
```

This checks the cameras zoom.
And in the external software I Receive
90 50 00 00 00 00 ff, which is correct.

My problem is that in my app if I debug im getting:

"?P\0\0"   .

Answer (score 0):

You are probably making a mistake setting the hardware flow control.

According to [the documentation](https://www.epiphan.com/userguides/networked-VGA-Grid/Content/UserGuides/Streaming/maintenance/thirdPartyConfig/man_br_3rdParty_controlling_with_rs232.htm#Connecti) of your camera you should only be using RTS/CTS but you are setting up your port for both RTS/CTS and DTR/DSR.

It might be a good idea to drop flow control altogether, if only to start with. For such slow baud rates and short data exchanges you probably won't need any kind of flow control anyway.

Comment: The first thing to try is to set `serialPort.DtrEnable = false;` I think the link I posted is for a different product. For your camera the documentation does not mention anything related to flow control, why are you using it? You might want to try to set both `serialPort.DtrEnable = false;` and `serialPort.DtrEnable = false;` to see what happens. There might be an option on the camera's menu, but I don't see it on the documentation

Comment: Ill try it tomorrow and let you know. Thank you! (I have them as true because testing)

Comment: Hey, so i tried it but nothing changed. With the read external software I can check that the command that ask for the info gets sent, but it doesnt return nothing. But if I send the same command with that software it returns the info

Comment: Have you checked the address and RS485 settings on the [menu](https://www.epiphan.com/userguides/LUMiO12x/Content/UserGuides/PTZ/3-operation/understandingOSDSettings.htm#OSD)? The address should be set to 1 and RS485 to disable.

Comment: First off you should display the out yot get from the port as hexadecimal, maybe something like `Debug.Log(String.Format("{0:X}", data));`, take a look at the documentation to see how formatting works. And second, I think some of your settings are still wrong, are you sure about baud rate and parity?

Comment: Ill try to convert it to hex, and yes im sure since I see it in the cameras documentation

Comment: OK, it might be just displaying as HEX,  P is ASCII 0x50 and you might have some NULL chars in there too.